# How to Open a Cash Drawer Programmatically in an Android device?

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

I'm currently working on a project where I need to open a cash drawer connected to an Android device using .NET MAUI. I've been trying to figure out how to achieve this, but I'm a bit stuck.

If anyone has experience with a similar setup or any tips on how to accomplish this, I would greatly appreciate your insights and advice!

Comment: Have you read the docs for the cash drawer?  What do they say about how to open it?  How is it connected to the Android device?

Comment: actually, I don't have the docs, because it was a used one.it connects through usb port

Comment: You should find them.  Some older cash drawers may open via a simple ASCII string, but newer ones may require something more complex.